# Se pide que el usuario escriba un string y se diga en que posicion aparece 'a' por primera vez y por ultima vez

Tags: python

- **Tengo esto, que me dice donde está la primera 'a' pero no sé como hacer para que tambien me diga donde está la última 'a'. Gracias de antemano.***

```
a=input('escribe un string: ')
c=list(a)

if 'a' in c:
    print('a  está en la posición', a.index('a'))
```

Comment: Encontrar el último en una lista no es tan directo como encontrar el primero. O bien iteras sobre la lista empezando por el final hasta encontrarlo, o bien usas `.index()` sobre la lista `reversed()`, y luego ajustas el índice restándolo de la longitud. En el caso de cadenas tienes `.rindex()` para buscar desde el final, pero en listas no

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te he modificado el mensaje de print para distinguir la primera con la última.
Con el método `rfind` lo que hace es buscar por el final y cuando la encuentra, para.

```
a=input('escribe un string: ')
c=list(a)

if 'a' in c:
    print('La primera a está en la posición ', a.index('a'))
    print('La última a está en la posición ', a.rfind('a'))
```

Comment: No es necesario convert a lista. `if 'a' in a:` funciona lo mismo.

Comment: He cogido el código de Leire y lo he adaptado, no soy partidario de ir cambiando código así porque sí, sin dar una explicación de porqué sí o porqué no. He probado con lista y sin lista y funcionaba de forma correcta, así que lo dejé como estaba. @CandidMoe